# Unsure as to how to format url in fstring

Tags: django

I've got the following code:

```
return f"<td class='eventyes'><a href='{% url 'accounts:daydetail' %}?{{ day }}'><span class='date'>{day}</span><ul><div class='singleevent'>{d}</div></ul></a></td>"
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
  File "<fstring>", line 1
    (% url 'accounts:daydetail' %)
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What syntax should I use to correctly format the name of the view within the anchor tag?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:

```
 url = reverse('accounts:day_detail')

 return f"<td class='eventyes'><a href='{url}'><span class='date'>{day}</span><ul><div class='singleevent'>{d}</div></ul></a></td>"
```

Answer (score 0):

My situation was almost the same.

I had `return f"<td><a href=""><span class='date'>{day}</span><ul>{d}</ul></a></td>"`

All I needed is to change double quotes to single quotes in `href` attribute:

```
return f"<td><a href=''><span class='date'>{day}</span><ul>{d}</ul></a></td>"
```

Answer (score -1):

If you switch around the single quotes for double quotes, it works:

```
return 'f<td class="eventyes"><a href="{% url "accounts:daydetail" %}?{{ day }}"><span class="date">{day}</span><ul><div class="singleevent">{d}</div></ul></a></td>'
```

Comment: Sorry. This doesn't work. the template tags are being rendered on the page with curly braces around them. It renders {{day}}{{d}} as text on the page.

Comment: i think i have to reverse the url first